# Pandas rename column names with certain patterns and do aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that looks like:

```
school  2010-01 2010-02 2010-03 2010-04 .... 201612
  A      500     497     501     512          512
  B      350     340     352     343          351
```

It contains a list of schools and numbers of headcount for each month. I want to **1)** change all the Jan-Mar to Q1, Apr-Jun to Q2, Jul-Sep to Q3 and Oct-Dec to Q4, eg: 2010-01 to 2010Q1, 2010-02 to 2010Q1, 2010-04 to 2010Q2.
**2)** then get the mean headcount of each quarter

Thank you!

Comment: You do not have Jan-Mar, etc. in your dataframe. What exactly do you want to change?

Answer (score 1):

consider `df`

```
pidx = pd.PeriodIndex(start='2010-01', end='2016-12', freq='M')

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(300, 600, size=(2, 84)),
    index=pd.Index(list('AB'), name='school'),
    columns=pidx
)

df
```

[image]

***solution***

```
df.groupby(df.columns.to_timestamp().to_period('Q'), axis=1).mean()
```

If your column values are strings... this will work

```
df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.columns).to_period('Q'), axis=1).mean()
```

[image]